# How to keep socket connection alive using when changing url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, routes, keep-alive

On frontend(reactjs) I have form for submitting the data before joining the room, since data has to be validated, I have onSubmit function that does that and if everything is ok redirects the user to `/drawing-page`, when that happens socket disconnects(socket.on('disconnect') triggers on backend).

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

export const formValidation = (username, room) => {
    if (!username || !room) {
        alert('Room and username must be provided');
        return false;
    }

    if (username.length < 4 || room.length < 4) {
        alert('Room and username must be at least 4 characters long');
        return false;
    }

    if (username.length > 30 || room.length > 30) {
        alert('Room and username can\'t be longer than 30 characters');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const username = e.target.username.value;
        const room = e.target.room.value;

        if (!formValidation(username, room)) {
            return;
        }

        socket.emit('join', { username, room }, error => {
            if (error) {
                alert(error);
                window.location.href = '/';
            }
        });

        window.location.href = '/drawing-page';
    }
```

Backend code:

```
socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
        console.log(`reason: ${reason}`);
        const user = removeUser(socket.id);

        if (user) {
            if (!io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(user.room)) {
                removeRoom(user.room);
                io.emit('showActiveRooms', getRooms());
            }
        }
    });
```

Because of **URL** change, socket disconnects, is there any way that I can make socket disconnect only when app closes and not when url changes

Answer (score 1):

The socket connection will lost on redirect because the socket connection is in `Form` Try moving it up to `App.js` and pass socket variable through props or context